# how to make android app that has offline maps

Tags: android, android-maps

i want to make a android app that already has the map tiles of a particular area in its apk and when the user installs the app he can see the map without having an internet connection in his phone. he should be able to see the map of that particular area offline. i have heard i could do this by osmdroid. but can i store actual Googlemaps (satellite view) with it.

Or is it possible to first store the png images of the map tiles of that particular area in your asset folder and then use it. if this is possible can you please tell me how to do this(i mean how to put tiles in asset folder and then display it using inputstream ). i am new to android. any help where to start from?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847353/use-google-maps-offline-in-an-app#5896100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but can i store actual Googlemaps (satellite view) with it.

OSMDroid does not use Google Maps. There is no API in Maps V2 to cache tiles for offline use, at least not at the present time.

> Or is it possible to first store the png images of the map tiles of that particular area in your asset folder and then use it.

You do not have Google Maps' map tiles as PNG images.

> i am new to android. any help where to start from?

Use OSMDroid. Or, find some commercial mapping library that offers offline maps.

Comment: this tool creates the map tiles of the selected area. all the map tiles generated by this tool are actually png images of 256*256 size. so is it possible to put them in asset folder and display using inputstream?

Comment: @user3190368: Not legally.